as.POSIXct results in NAs for some of my data
I want to convert my date column into
Reproducible dataset:
structure(list(rownum = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4338L, 10694L, 
24305L, 29262L, 36277L, 48599L, 57181L, 65107L, 68320L, 74071L
), date = c("2022-04-05 22:00", "2022-04-05 23:00", "2022-04-06 00:00", 
"2022-04-06 01:00", "2022-04-06 02:00", "2022-10-02 02:00", "2023-10-01 02:00", 
"2022-10-02 02:00", "2023-10-01 02:00", "2021-10-03 02:00", "2021-10-03 02:00", 
"2022-10-02 02:00", "2021-10-03 02:00", "2021-10-03 02:00", "2022-10-02 02:00"
), year = c(2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2023L, 
2022L, 2023L, 2021L, 2021L, 2022L, 2021L, 2021L, 2022L), month = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L), day = c(5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L), hour = c(22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4317L, 
10648L, 18112L, 23041L, 29949L, 42012L, 46606L, 53202L, 56415L, 
62166L), class = "data.frame")

if I then run this code:
data_samp$date <- as.POSIXct(data_samp$date, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "Australia/Sydney")

You can see that rows 1-5 have the correct date, whereas the rest of the rows are all NAs – despite having converted to POSIXct.
> str(data_samp)
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ rownum: int  1 2 3 4 5 4338 10694 24305 29262 36277 ...
 $ date  : POSIXct, format: "2022-04-05 22:00:00" "2022-04-05 23:00:00" "2022-04-06 00:00:00" "2022-04-06 01:00:00" ...



I have a much larger dataset of 66,753 rows, of which just 10 rows come out with an NA once I try to convert them. I have no idea why. The troublesome dates are: 2am on 3rd October 2021; 2am on 2nd October 2022; 2am on 1st October 2023. No other time of day has an issue other than 2am.
Edit – I managed to fix it using:
tz="ETC/GMT+10")

instead of tz="Australia/Sydney" (or no tz definition).
But I still don't understand why this fixes it – I assume something to do with daylight savings maybe? An explanation of what is happening here would be helpful!

I can see why some people would think this was a programming question, and try to delete it, but I think those people would be wrong. I

There was no 2am in Australia/Sydney on  2022-10-02
> before<-as.POSIXct("2022-10-02 01:59",tz = "Australia/Sydney")
> after<-as.POSIXct("2022-10-02 03:00",tz = "Australia/Sydney")
> before
[1] "2022-10-02 01:59:00 AEST"
> after
[1] "2022-10-02 03:00:00 AEDT"
> after-before
Time difference of 1 mins

The minute after 1:59am AEST was 3am AEDT, because of the start of daylight savings.
If you have a time stamp of 2022-10-02 02:00 then it can't have been produced by a system correctly following the Australia/Sydney time zone. It also can't have been correctly following AEST (which was over by then) or AEDT (which didn't have a 2am that night).
It was presumably a system that hadn't done the switch to summer time, and so can accurately be described as in UTC+10. In UTC+10, 2022-10-02 01:59 was followed a minute later by 2022-10-02 02:00, as you'd naively expect.
You might wonder whether it's really necessary for as.POSIXct to be so bloody-mindedly pedantic about time zones. Sadly, it probably is. The alternatives are worse. In any case, R trusts the operating system to do the conversion and so has to live with what it reports.

That is a great catch!
